# Are there plans to remove the mouse cursor in uTouch?

Tags: multi-touch, ipad

I notice in the demo video of uTouch that the standard mouse pointer is still showing. Are there plans to remove the mouse cursor?

This is one of the most annoying things when using touch technology on PC tablets. This was also my issue with the Android port for PC. People with touch screen device's don't want an annoying cursor to show anywhere on the screen because, it's distracting. Touch technology needs to seem natural and allow the user to interact with objects on the screen much like objects in the physical world. Don't get me wrong, I love Ubuntu and that is all I run on my PC's. However when you see a 2 or 3 year old using an Apple iPad without having to be taught to interface with it, you know you have designed a great UI experience.

It's great to see this coming into reality on Ubuntu keep up the good work.

Are their plans to make Ubuntu\uTouch more natural for touch device users?

Comment: Not as far as I know - It doesn't seem to be that wanted. I currently use unity on my tablet, and, due to the "desktop-ness" of the OS I would rather have a cursor showing.

Comment: You could always make a completely transparent mouse theme ;)

Answer (score 1):

See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660613/how-do-you-hide-the-mouse-pointer-under-linux-x11

It looks like there are no plans to do anything about this issue, if you would like it to have some attention, please report it as a bug: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs